# Frame by Frame Animation with many particles?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

What is the best way to draw frame by frame animations when there are many particles on the screen?
Currently using a uigraphicsimagerenderer with a cadisplaylink. Every refresh the image is redrawn but on an older device there are performance issues because I want to draw a lot of small points which are all calculated every frame (one new point is added and the oldest is removed, so the points in the middle would stay at position, perhaps a thing to optimize something?).
Any suggestions to improve this to get constant framerates although there are a lot of „particles“

Answer (score 3):

[SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/) is great for implementing high-performance particle systems. It's highly tweakable and has a powerful WYSIWYG particle editor built into Xcode.

Custom solutions using Core Animation typically lack these advantages unless you really know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: The problem is, that I wanna have a trace of an object which position changes every frame with some amount. So I have to position each single particle.

Comment: I don’t know if this is the best way but I added childs in SpriteKit and removed one of them each frame but the rest are staying.

Answer (score 0):

iOS device hardware is not well suited to frame-by-frame rendering. At the hardware level it supports tiled rendering, backed by CALayer objects. You are much better off taking advantage of the way the rendering engine works. There is a rich particle generation system, for example. You set up particle generators and the OS takes care of rendering them.